# R: removing "backwards" duplicate rows to construct an edgeMatrix

Tags: r, matrix, graph

I want to create an undirected graph in R using the *graph* package. 
I wanted to use

`edge.matrix <- unique(edge.matrix, MARGIN = 2, drop=TRUE)
 mygraph <- ftM2graphNEL(edge.matrix, edgemode="directed")`

but I get the error message

`Error in .ftM2other(ft, W, V, edgemode, "graphNEL") : 
  duplicate edges not allowed`

The problem is that the function sees as equal even rows which are mirrored, such as `A, B` and `B, A`, so I have to find a way
 to delete the rows which are "backwards" the same.

An example: say my matrix is

`A   B
 C   D 
 B   A`,

I want to get

`A   B
 C   D`
or

`C   D 
 B   A`

(sorry for the layout, I am not so practical yet).

The naive idea was to write a function which takes the row `matrix[i,]`, mirrors it, checks if the matrix `matrix[i+1 : nrow(matrix), ]` contains the mirrored row and possibly removes it. Unfortunately the computational time would be ~n!/2. I don't think it would be much better even if I dropped the first or followings occourrence(s) in the remaining matrix, since my matrix has ~30k rows.

The  *graph* package does have a *duplicatedEdges* function, but it does not what I need.

Any idea? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: This is one way, check for duplicates `idx <- !duplicated(t(apply(edge.matrix,  1, sort)))` then subset `edge.matrix[idx, ]` .Wont be that efficient but for 30K rows will stil be seconds

Comment: Oh, i also got `ftM2graphNEL` to work for your example matrix. To get the warning that you got, there are *actual duplicate*. rows You can remove these with `edge.matrixnew <- edge.matrix[!duplicated(edge.matrix ), ]`

Comment: Thank you @user20650 , it worked! Just I found out, when I wanted to do an undirecred graph, I still got the error. So I simply applied `ugraph` to the directed graph, but I am not sure this is the best way to do it.